# How to generate an Unique ID based on criteria from a UserForm

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a USerForm for patient registration, in said UserForm there is a combobox for selecting the primary doctor I would like a way to generate patient ID based on the doctor selection, I dont even where to start I do want the code to evaluate which was the last ID with the same prefix to generate the next one e.g.

```
KT000001
KT000002
LG000001
```

Here is the UserForm Code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Lista Pacientes")

'find first empty row in database
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

'check for a Valid patient name
If Trim(Me.TextBox1.Value) = "" Then
  Me.TextBox1.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Favor Introducir Nombre"
  Exit Sub
End If

With ws
  .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 8).Value = Me.TextBox6.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 10).Value = Me.TextBox7.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 11).Value = Me.TextBox8.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 12).Value = Me.TextBox9.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 13).Value = Me.TextBox10.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 14).Value = Me.TextBox11.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 15).Value = Me.TextBox12.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 16).Value = Me.TextBox13.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 17).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 6).FormulaLocal = "=CONCATENAR(LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(B" & iRow & "));SI(LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(C" & iRow & "))="""";"""";"" "");LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(C" & iRow & "));SI(LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(D" & iRow & "))="""";"""";"" "");LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(D" & iRow & "));SI(LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(E" & iRow & "))="""";"""";"" "");LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(E" & iRow & ")))"
  .Cells(iRow, 9).FormulaLocal = "=SIFECHA(H" & iRow & ";HOY();""Y"")"


End With

'clear the data
Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
Me.TextBox2.Value = ""
Me.TextBox3.Value = ""
Me.TextBox4.Value = ""
Me.TextBox5.Value = ""
Me.TextBox6.Value = ""
Me.TextBox7.Value = ""
Me.TextBox8.Value = ""
Me.TextBox9.Value = ""
Me.TextBox10.Value = ""
Me.TextBox11.Value = ""
Me.TextBox12.Value = ""
Me.TextBox13.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox1.Value = ""
Me.TextBox1.SetFocus

Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
  Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you asking how to increment a given ID (`KT000001` -> `KT000002`) or how to create a completely new one (`patient data` -> `KT000001`)?

Comment: I would do a temporary table on a seperate worksheet containing doctors lists in one column and "next patient ID" in second one. After you add a patient to a database, you increment patient index next to the chosen doctor. And you always know what's the next number for each doctor.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct Create a Completly new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could go like follows (mind the comments):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Dim IDCol As Long '<~~ this will hold the unique patient ID column index
    Dim nDoc As Long '<~~ this will count the number of occurrences of the chosen doctor ID in the patient ID column
    Dim docID As String '<~~ this will holed the doctor ID value (retrieved from ComboBox1)


    'check for a Valid patient name. <~~ do that at the beginning of the sub, not to run code uselessly
    If Trim(Me.TextBox1.Value) = "" Then
      Me.TextBox1.SetFocus
      MsgBox "Favor Introducir Nombre"
      Exit Sub
    End If

    IDCol = 17 '<~~ this is the column index where to write unique patient IDs. change it to your needs
    docID = Me.ComboBox1.Value '<~~ retrieve the doctor ID value from ComboBox1
    Set ws = Worksheets("Lista Pacientes")
    With ws
        'find first empty row in database
        iRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

        nDoc = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells(1, IDCol).Resize(iRow), docID & "*") '<~~ count the number of occurrences of the chosen doctor ID in the patient ID column
        .Cells(iRow, IDCol).Value = docID & Format(nDoc + 1, "000000") '<~~ write patient unique ID

        '...rest of your code here
    End With

    '...rest of your code here
End Sub
```

Comment: Reading the code I noticed `docID = Me.ComboBox1.Value '<~~ retrieve the doctor ID value from ComboBox1` ComboBox1 is the name of the Doctor so I guess it should be something like `docID = If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Doctor name 1" 
Then "KP"
Else "LP"` Does that make sense is that how it works? @user3598756

Comment: I assumed that the combobox is already populated with doctors IDs. Should not that be the case and Combobox be populated with doctors real names ("John Doe"; "Mark Smith",...) to be associated with corresponding IDs ("KP", "LP", ...) then it can be easily done with lookups. Of course there must be a place (a Range?) where to read both doctors name and their corresponding ID from

Comment: I did a small test with 
`Select Case Me.ComboBox1.Value
    Case Is = "Agent 1"
        docID = "AGT1"
    Case Is = "Agent 2"
        docID = "AGT2"
    Case Is = "Agent 3"
        docID = "AGT3"
    Case Is = "Agent 4"
        docID = "AGT4"
End Select`
And it worked later on I'll incorporate it to my original code and see how it goes

Comment: if the real `ComboBox1` values and corresponding `docID` ones are those you showed in the comment then there's no need for a `Select Case` block and simply go `docID = "AGT" & Right(Me.ComboBox1.Value,1)`

Comment: No that was just a test It's now working, I'll post it as an answer, thanks for your help you really helped me crack that nut open

Comment: you're welcome. you could then accept my answer as solution to your _original_ question i.e.: _"I would like a way to generate patient ID based on the doctor selection"_. thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is my final working code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim IDCol As Long
Dim nDoc As Long
Dim docID As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Lista Pacientes")

'find first empty row in database
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

'check for a valid patient first name
If Trim(Me.TextBox1.Value) = "" Then
  Me.TextBox1.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Favor Introducir Nombre"
  Exit Sub
End If

'copy the data to the database

IDCol = 1

Select Case Me.ComboBox1.Value
    Case Is = "Dra. Lilaruth Gonzalez Montenegro"
        docID = "LG"
    Case Is = "Dr. Keneth Algo"
        docID = "KP"
    Case Is = "Dra. Aida Espinoza"
        docID = "AE"


End Select

With ws
nDoc = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells(1, IDCol).Resize(iRow), docID & "*")
.Cells(iRow, IDCol).Value = docID & Format(nDoc + 1, "000000")

  .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 8).Value = Me.TextBox6.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 10).Value = Me.TextBox7.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 11).Value = Me.TextBox8.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 12).Value = Me.TextBox9.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 13).Value = Me.TextBox10.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 14).Value = Me.TextBox11.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 15).Value = Me.TextBox12.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 16).Value = Me.TextBox13.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 17).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 6).FormulaLocal = "=CONCATENAR(LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(B" & iRow & ")),SI(LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(C" & iRow & "))="""","""","" ""),LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(C" & iRow & ")),SI(LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(D" & iRow & "))="""","""","" ""),LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(D" & iRow & ")),SI(LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(E" & iRow & "))="""","""","" ""),LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(E" & iRow & ")))"
  .Cells(iRow, 9).FormulaLocal = "=SIFECHA(H" & iRow & ",HOY(),""Y"")"

End With

'clear the data
Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
Me.TextBox2.Value = ""
Me.TextBox3.Value = ""
Me.TextBox4.Value = ""
Me.TextBox5.Value = ""
Me.TextBox6.Value = ""
Me.TextBox7.Value = ""
Me.TextBox8.Value = ""
Me.TextBox9.Value = ""
Me.TextBox10.Value = ""
Me.TextBox11.Value = ""
Me.TextBox12.Value = ""
Me.TextBox13.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox1.Value = ""
Me.TextBox1.SetFocus


End Sub
```